# How to make image centered in a larger container without having extra space beneath it?

Tags: css

I have a div with its width being 460px. The div's background is black. It contains an image with its width being 400px.

I need to center the image in the div without having the extra space beneath the image. I can remove the space by making the image display as block, but it makes the image display not in the center position.

Here is the jsfillde demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/g43Pp/

Here is the code

```
<div class="img-holder"> 
    <img src="myimage.jpg" />        
</div>

div.img-holder {
    width: 460px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am looking for a CSS solution. The div's display property has to be block and it cannot be float.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with margins:

```
.img-holder {
    width: 460px;
    background-color: black;
}
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin: auto` when you set it's display to block

http://jsfiddle.net/g43Pp/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to what you've already got.

```
.img-holder img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the bottom margin's value, by this, you won't have to make it a `block` element.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g43Pp/3/)